# Is it necessary to implement SwipeToRefresh when using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiperefreshlayout

I started working on a news android app and thought of using firebase to disseminate latest news to my blog readers. So after playing with firebase for couple of days i was able to create database for my app.

Having done that, i thought of adding SwipeRefresh feature to my app so users can swipe to get latest news posted in my database.

But it occurred to me that since firebase database is realtime as we all know, is it necessary to add the swipe to refresh feature when i could just update and deliver news content to my blog readers on the fly?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you right, you dont need a swipeToRefresh! =)
That`s the awesome thing about real time databases!

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do as long as you implement your Firebase listeners correctly then you will eliminate the burden on users to refresh data...that's part of the awesomeness of the real-time database.

Comment: As above comments mentioned, you don't have to. Any updates to the database will be synced with the app instantly.

Comment: Great comments all. I think these would make valid answers to the question, if elaborated a bit.

Comment: @LucasPaolillo I agree, but if lots of users are adding to your database, the RecyclerView will seem like it's glitching out due to the constant addition of rows.

Comment: @AbAppletic The decision to display info with realtime updates via a RecyclerView depends a lot on what your app is trying to accomplish, using a RecyclerView may not be the best option all of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Firebase database is a **Realtime Database** that updates your RecyclerView/Listview, or any view **automatically** whenever there is a change.

---

However, don't forget, when you add a single `ValueEventListener`  by `database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent();`, **the method will only be called once *EVEN WHEN UPDATED***. If you don't want that, you use the method `database.addValueEventListener()`.

Note that you can't **yet** implement "Swipe-to-refresh" to a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` /`FirebaseListAdapter`, for that requires you to disable the auto-sync feature, which isn't directly possible.